# JPA EclipseLink - updating entity relationships

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, h2

I have a JavaFX application that uses the eclipselink JPA provider to access a local H2 databse. I'm getting some strange behaviour when inserting or deleting objects, maybe it's a basic mechanism that I haven't understood yet.
I use this method to delete an entity that is referenced by an owning entity:

```
public static void delete(Object entry) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(entry);
        em.getTransaction().commit();          
    }
```

after this, I try to update the whole view by retrieving all entities from the DB:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> List<T> getAll(Class<?> c) {      
    var entries = getAllQuery(c).getResultList();       
    return entries;
}
```

but it seems that I only get the old DB state, with the newly inserted or deleted entities not in there. What's the best way to fix this? Should I manually remove the child entities from the owning entity before updating the view?

Comment: You have to remove it from the parent/containing class, and save that. and of you then activated `@xTox(orphanRemoval = true)` in the parent/containing class relationship to the target class, the item gets removed from DB on its own. (replace the x's with 'One' or 'Many')

Comment: Are you reading from a long lived EntityManager? EntityManagers are meant to represent units of work so maintain a cache. You might want to clear or close and obtain a new Entitymanager at certain points, like after commiting a transaction.